# What are some of the bigger differences world wide in VFR charts?

Tags: navigation, visual-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts

While discussing Aviation Charts in [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/when-flying-vfr-without-gps-how-do-pilots-know-if-they-are-inside-controlled-ai/52589#52589) SE question, *JanHudec* &  *Jwentin* commented that VFR chart ***symbols are not internationally standardized*** - including airspace names and procedures.

What are some of the most important differences world wide compared to FAA (NOAA)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: To start this off, notice the UK chart does not provide degree marks as easily read on the compass rose around the VOR which appears to make route planning much slower and heading not as easily confirmed.

Comment: The CAA chart pictured is a 1:250000 which (in my experience) is usually used for confined flying - you might use one if you're gliding, regularly conducting local flights, or flying a helicopter in a specific area. I've never seen one used. You certainly wouldn't use one for cross country flying. This would be a fairer comparison of the chart that's usually used (1:500000) https://www.memory-map.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/1/7/17_caa500.jpg

Comment: @BDLPPL Quarter-mil charts are sometimes used for cross-country flying in slower historical aircraft, where the extra landmarks are useful for navigation without radio aids, the slow speed means you don't need the area of the half-mil chart, and you're not high enough to need the airspaces marked on the half-mil chart - pretty similar to the glider flying you mention.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13369/62)